# Why does matshow come with ticks at negative values (and not show them)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = np.zeros((10, 10))
plt.matshow(m)
ax = plt.gca()
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
print ticks

>>> array([ -2., 0., 2., 4., 6., 8., 10.])
```

Why is there a tick at -2? The plot does not show a tick at -2.